# Density of smooth functions.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding denseness of $C^\infty$ in $L^p$ space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147923/understanding-denseness-of-c-infty-in-lp-space)

I am looking for a proof that shows $C^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$ . 
Any hints would be appreciated. 
Where $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: What is $\Omega$?

Comment: Its a bounded, open connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: 1. Show the continuous functions with compact support are dense. 2. Use [mollifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) to approximate continuous functions uniformly by smooth functions.

Comment: @t.b. can you explain me why do we have to take continuous functions to have compact support ?

Comment: @Ananda I would think that's because otherwise you're not sure whether the convolution exists. But if $f,g$ both have compact support then $f \ast g$ exists. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Compactly_supported_functions).

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67370/smooth-functions-with-compact-support-are-dense-in-l1) is related.

Comment: Aren't polynomials dense in $L^p(\Omega)$?

Comment: Ok, I missed that your $\Omega$ is open. But again, [this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/240A-C-03-04/Lecture_Notes/Older-Versions/chap22.pdf) might be helpful ;-)