# If $\int_{\Omega} (f(x)\varphi(x) +g(x)\varphi^{\prime}(x)) dx=0$, what it can be said about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain and let $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$. Let $f, g:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be two smooth functions. Consider the equation
$$\int_{\Omega} (f(x)\varphi(x) +g(x)\varphi^{\prime}(x)) dx=0.$$

My question is: there is relation between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? It is true that $f(x)=g(x)=0$ a.e.?

About me the answer to the last question is no. Firstly, since $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$, thus so it is $\varphi^{\prime}$. Moreover, I think that we can only say that $f(x)=-g(x)$ a.e. and they have not to be necessarily $0$.

Could someone please tell me if am I wrong and/or help me to answer also the first question?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ arbitrary?

Comment: If I remember correctly, $\int_{\Omega} (f(x)\varphi(x) +g(x)\varphi'(x)) dx = \int_{\Omega} (f(x) -g'(x)\varphi(x)) dx$, if that is zero for all test functions $\phi$ then $f-g'=0$.

Comment: Same comment as @xpaul: You should place a $\forall \varphi \in C_c^{\infty}$ in front of your formula.

Comment: Use linearity of integral operator, to separate. Then use integration by part. (And you will got what Martin R said.)

Comment: Please, as I said, modify your text by saying that your formula is valid for all $\varphi$. If it is valid for a particular $\varphi$ you can conclude nothing at all.

Comment: I have downvoted your question because you don't attempt to improve your text. I will erase the downvoting once you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from [Green's first identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green%27s_first_identity) (the [higher dimensional equivalent of integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Green%27s_first_identity)), that
$$ \tag{$*$}
\int_{\Omega} (f(x)\varphi(x) +g(x)\varphi^\prime(x)) dx = \int_{\Omega} (f(x) -g^\prime(x))\varphi(x) dx = 0\, .
$$

This is for example satisfied if the support of $f-g^\prime$ and the support of $\varphi$ are disjoint. So one can not conclude much about $f$ and $g$ if $(*)$ holds for *some* $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$.

But if $(*)$ holds for *all* test functions $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ then necessarily $f-g^\prime = 0$.

*Explanation of $(*)$:* Choose $U \subset \Omega$ such that the support of $\varphi$ is contained in $U$. Then
$$
\int_\Omega (g(x)\varphi'(x) - g'(x) \varphi(x)) \, dx
= \int_U(g(x)\varphi'(x) - g'(x) \varphi(x)) \, dx\\
= \int_{\partial U} g(x) \varphi(x) \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = 0
$$
since $\varphi$ vanishes on the boundary and outside of $U$.

Comment: Martin R, thank you for your answer. So, in general, it is false that $f=g$ a.e., isn't it? Moreover, could you please better explain why $f$ does not have multiplication neither $\varphi$ nor $\varphi^{\prime}$? It is not clear for me by using the link you quoted. Thank you.

Comment: @C.Bishop: Sorry, it is unclear to me what you are asking. If the integral is zero for all test functions then $f=g'$, and vice versa. What does “f does not have multiplication ...” mean?

Comment: Martin R, it is not clear the first "=" in $(*)$.

Comment: @C.Bishop: Since $\varphi$ has compact support, you can choose $U \subset \Omega$ such that the support of $\varphi$ is contained in $U$. Then apply Green's identity and note that that the integrals $\int_{\partial U}$ vanish. See for example the second formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Green%27s_first_identity

Comment: Martin R, sorry again, bu why it vanishes in the boundary?

Comment: @C.Bishop: Because $\varphi$ is zero on the boundary.

Comment: @J.G: Thanks for your edit. There was indeed a missing closing parenthesis. For the notion of derivatives, `g'` is *equivalent* to `g^\prime`, compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87134/28519.

Comment: @MartinR I'll remember to be lazier with my $'$s in the future.

Comment: @C.Bishop: I have added more details.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to prove this would be distribution-theory.
$\int_{\Omega}g(x)\varphi'(x) \,dx =  -\int_{\Omega}g'(x)\varphi(x) \,dx\: \forall  \varphi(x) \in \mathscr{C}^{\infty}_c$
where by g' I mean the "distributional-derivative".

Then we get that
$\int_{\Omega}f(x)\varphi(x) \,dx = \int_{\Omega}g'(x)\varphi(x) \,dx$ 
This means precisely that f and g' are equal in "the distributional sense".
If we assume that $f,g' \in L^{1}_{loc}$ then we can apply the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations.

See [Proof of fundamental lemma of calculus of variation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017662/proof-of-fundamental-lemma-of-calculus-of-variation)

And get $f(x) = g'(x)$ almost everywhere.
So you see that smoothness of $f,g$ is a very strong assumption that is not needed at all.

(P.S: I deleted the earlier post because I missed the prime over $\varphi$ there)

Comment: Paul Joh, I have the multiplication for $\varphi^{\prime}$, too.

Comment: Thank you I corrected it !