# Lebesgue integral of a difference of functions.

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-measure

I would like to prove that if $ \delta $ is close enough to zero then Lebesgue Integral:
$ \int_{R} {}|f(x) - f(x + \delta)| dx  $ is less then $ \epsilon $ for any $ \epsilon>0 $
,where f belongs to $ L^{1}( R ) $ space

Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you prove it for $f = \mathbb{1}_E$ ($E$ measurable of finite measure), or for continuous functions with compact support, for instance ?

Comment: Yes, I can.If a continuous function has a compact support, then it is uniformly continuous on that set and it goes easy from this moment.And it's easy to prove it for a function, which has a finite value set.But I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Hint : the set $C_c(\mathbb R)$ of continuous functions with compact support is [dense](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67370/smooth-functions-with-compact-support-are-dense-in-l1?rq=1) in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, meaning that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists g \in C_c(\mathbb R) \int |f-g| < \epsilon / 2$.

Comment: It's not a fact that I should be aware of , but I will definitely try it out.Thank you.