# Check whether the following proof works for " $C_{c}^{\infty}$ is a dense subset of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$"

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Kindly see the below proof. This is from stackexchange. Here the author has shown that  $C_{c}^{\infty}$ is a dense subset of $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$".

I think the proof works well even for $L^{2}$. I  have to put $| \;|^2$ (use $L^2$ norm)  while doing the calculation for  $\|g - g_\varepsilon \| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Am I right ?

Link : [Smooth functions with compact support are dense in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67370/smooth-functions-with-compact-support-are-dense-in-l1)

> We can ignore the information that $J_\varepsilon$ is a mollifier. All we need is a smooth function with integral one. $J_\varepsilon$ is such a function as proven in a) in the question above.
>
> We will use that $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^1$ to show that $C_c^\infty(X)$ is also dense in $L^1$ where $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $f \in L^1$. Then by density of $C_c(X)$ there is a $g$ in $C_c(X)$ such that $\| f - g \|_{L^1} < \epsilon$.
>
> Now we need to turn $g$ into a smooth function by convolving it with $J_\varepsilon$. Let $$g_\varepsilon (x) := (J_\varepsilon \ast g ) (x) = \int_\mathbb{R} J_\varepsilon(x - y) g(y) dy$$
>
> Then $g_\varepsilon$ is smooth because $\left ( f \ast g \right )^\prime = f^\prime \ast g = f \ast g^\prime$ and $J_\varepsilon$ is infinitely differentiable.
>
> $g_\varepsilon$ has compact support because if $[-S,S]$ is the support of $g$ and $[-R,R]$ is the support of $J_\varepsilon$ then the support of $J_\varepsilon \ast g$ is contained in $[-S - R, S + R]$ and hence is also compact.
>
> To finish the proof we claim that $\| f - g_\varepsilon \|_{L^1} < \epsilon$:
>
> $$ \| f - g_\varepsilon \| \leq \| f - g \| + \|g - g_\varepsilon \| < \epsilon$$
>
> Where $\| f - g \| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ holds because $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^1$ and $\|g - g_\varepsilon \| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ holds because:
>
> $$\begin{align}
>  \|g - g_\varepsilon \|_{L^1} = \int_X \left | g(z) - g_\varepsilon (z)\right | dz 
> &= \int_X \left | g(z) - \int_\mathbb{R} J_\varepsilon(z -y) g(y) dy \right | dz \\
>  &= \int_X \left | g(z)\int_\mathbb{R}J_\varepsilon(y)dy - \int_\mathbb{R}J_\varepsilon(z -y) g(y) dy \right | dz\\
>  &\stackrel{(*)}{=} \int_X \left | g(z)\int_\mathbb{R}J_\varepsilon(z - y)dy - \int_\mathbb{R}J_\varepsilon(z -y) g(y) dy \right | dz \\
>  &= \int_X \left | \int_\mathbb{R} g(z) J_\varepsilon(z - y)dy - \int_\mathbb{R}J_\varepsilon(z -y) g(y) dy \right | dz \\
> &\leq \int_X  \int_\mathbb{R} | g(z) J_\varepsilon(z - y) |dy - \int_\mathbb{R} | J_\varepsilon(z -y) g(y) | dy  dz \\
> &= \int_X \int_\mathbb{R} |g(z) - g(y)| J_\varepsilon (z -y) dy dz
> \end{align}$$
>
> Where the equality marked with (*) holds because the integral is over all of $\mathbb{R}$ so the shift by the constant $z$ doesn't change the integral and $J_\varepsilon$ is even hence $J_\varepsilon (y) = J_\varepsilon (-y)$.
>
> $g$ is continuous and compactly supported hence it is uniformly continuous and so there exists a $\delta$ such that $|g(z) - g(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 \lambda(X)}$ for all $z,y \in X$ hence by choosing $\varepsilon := \delta$ we get
>
> $$ \int_X \int_\mathbb{R} |g(z) - g(y)| J_\delta (z -y) dy dz < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$
>
> Note that $\epsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ are not the same.

Comment: What is your question ? Yes $f \ast J_\epsilon \to f$ in $L^p,p \ge 1$