# Prove For $\epsilon >0$ exists a $g$ function bounded such that $g$ is integrable and $|f(x)dx-\int{g(x)}dx|<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Prove For $\epsilon >0$ exists a $g$ function bounded such that $g$ is integrable and
$$\left|\int{f(x)}dx-\int{g(x)}dx\right|<\epsilon$$ where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is a lebesgue integrable.

I think this problem can be solved using a Dominate convergence theorem but i don't have a clear idea of how solve this. can someone help me?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why can't I just take $g=f$?

Comment: @saulspatz edited

Comment: @FengShao edited

Comment: There is a standard result which says functions in $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ are dense in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ from where you can claim that there is a continuous function with compact support satisfying your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $f<\infty$ a.e. Let $$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)&\text{if}\ |f(x)|\leq n,\\0&\text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$ then $g_n\to f$ a.e. Now use DCT to obtain $$\int g_n\,dx \to \int f\,dx.$$By the definition of limit, there exists $N$ such that the inequality in the post holds for all $n>N$. Let $g=g_{N+1}$ so $g$ is bounded by $N+1$.

**Remark.** In deed, we can prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a smooth function $g$ with compact support such that
$$\left|\int f(x)\,dx-\int g(x)\,dx\right|<\epsilon,$$
where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is a lebesgue integrable function.

See here: [Smooth functions with compact support are dense in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67370/smooth-functions-with-compact-support-are-dense-in-l1?rq=1)